# phoenix select view Undefined column

Tags: apache-phoenix

create view for existing table in hbase

```
create view "xxx"."traffic"(
            "guid" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
            "src"."srcmac" VARCHAR,
            "info"."downsize" VARCHAR
            );

use "xxx";
```

why get error

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:node1:2181> select * from "traffic" where "src.srcmac"="00:0c:29:46:69:92";
Error: ERROR 504 (42703): Undefined column. columnName=xxx.traffic.src.srcmac (state=42703,code=504)
```

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:node1:2181> select * from "traffic" where "guid"="6773891525274486511";
Error: ERROR 504 (42703): Undefined column. columnName=xxx.traffic.6773891525274486511 (state=42703,code=504)
org.apache.phoenix.schema.ColumnNotFoundException: ERROR 504 (42703): Undefined column. columnName=xxx.traffic.6773891525274486511
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.getColumnForColumnName(PTableImpl.java:828)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$SingleTableColumnResolver.resolveColumn(FromCompiler.java:477)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ExpressionCompiler.resolveColumn(ExpressionCompiler.java:372)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.WhereCompiler$WhereExpressionCompiler.resolveColumn(WhereCompiler.java:191)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.WhereCompiler$WhereExpressionCompiler.visit(WhereCompiler.java:177)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.WhereCompiler$WhereExpressionCompiler.visit(WhereCompiler.java:164)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.ColumnParseNode.accept(ColumnParseNode.java:56)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.CompoundParseNode.acceptChildren(CompoundParseNode.java:64)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.ComparisonParseNode.accept(ComparisonParseNode.java:45)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.WhereCompiler.compile(WhereCompiler.java:138)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.WhereCompiler.compile(WhereCompiler.java:108)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleFlatQuery(QueryCompiler.java:556)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleQuery(QueryCompiler.java:507)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSelect(QueryCompiler.java:193)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:153)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:490)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:456)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:302)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:291)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:290)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:283)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1830)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:813)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:686)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)
```

Comment: I'm assuming string values should be single quoted as in `select * from "traffic" where "guid"='6773891525274486511'`

Comment: Thanks, it works. The quote in phoenix make me crazy